# make app universally compatible for device with and without camera

Tags: android, google-play

I face a strange problem, 
My application works perfectly on devices with or without a camera; only a few functionalities are not available if you don't have a camera.

After uploading my app to the play store, the play store excluded some devices without a camera in which the app actually works fine!

By using this permission:

```
              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

play store auto excludes.

Has anybody faced similar problems?

Sorry if this is a duplicate (I hope it is not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html):

> In some cases, the permissions that you request through  can affect how your application is filtered by Google Play.
>
> If you request a hardware-related permission — CAMERA, for example — Google Play assumes that your application requires the underlying hardware feature and filters the application from devices that do not offer it.
>
> To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in  elements, rather than relying on Google Play to "discover" the requirements in  elements. Then, if you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a android:required="false" attribute to the  declaration.

So, just add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: Dear FD you made by day , your solution worked thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

I know at least for features there is an option to set if it isrequired or not . You could try that.

Just add required=false in the permission declaration.

Comment: Be careful to distinguish between `uses-feature` and `uses-permission` ;)

Comment: I didn't say for sure it was right, just that I had seen similar things for features. I would say your answer will probably do it.